# Delete columns/rows with more than x% missing

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to delete all columns or rows with more than 50% `NA`s in a data frame.

This is my solution:

```
# delete columns with more than 50% missings
miss <- c()
for(i in 1:ncol(data)) {
  if(length(which(is.na(data[,i]))) > 0.5*nrow(data)) miss <- append(miss,i) 
}
data2 <- data[,-miss]


# delete rows with more than 50% percent missing
miss2 <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if(length(which(is.na(data[i,]))) > 0.5*ncol(data)) miss2 <- append(miss2,i) 
}
data <- data[-miss,]
```

but I'm looking for a nicer/faster solution.

I would also appreciate a `dplyr` solution

Comment: @Ricky I added my row solution, which is pretty much the same

Comment: To confirm my understanding for the additional row solution: So if row X initially has more than 50% NA, but after column 3 is removed than column X has fewer than 50% NA, row X should not be removed?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To remove columns with some amount of NA, you can use
`colMeans(is.na(...))`

```
## Some sample data
set.seed(0)
dat <- matrix(1:100, 10, 10)
dat[sample(1:100, 50)] <- NA
dat <- data.frame(dat)

## Remove columns with more than 50% NA
dat[, which(colMeans(!is.na(dat)) > 0.5)]

## Remove rows with more than 50% NA
dat[which(rowMeans(!is.na(dat)) > 0.5), ]

## Remove columns and rows with more than 50% NA
dat[which(rowMeans(!is.na(dat)) > 0.5), which(colMeans(!is.na(dat)) > 0.5)]
```

Comment: so it's `dat[-which(rowMeans(is.na(dat)) > 0.5), ]` for rows. thanks!

Comment: @spore234 HTH @PierreLafortune after a quick test it seems to be about 3x as fast as an equivalent `sapply` solution

Answer (score 17):

A `tidyverse` solution that removes columns with an x% of `NA`s(50%) here:

```
test_data <- data.frame(A=c(rep(NA,12),
                            520,233,522),
                        B = c(rep(10,12),
                              520,233,522))
# Remove all with %NA >= 50
# can just use >50


 test_data %>% 
  purrr::discard(~sum(is.na(.x))/length(.x)* 100 >=50)
```

Result:

```
     B
1   10
2   10
3   10
4   10
5   10
6   10
7   10
8   10
9   10
10  10
11  10
12  10
13 520
14 233
15 522
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use this method to drop any group in a grouped data.frame with more than 50% missing values for one column?

Comment: Without actual data, it's hard to test but you can do something like: `df %>% 
  group_by(grouping_col) %>% 
  filter(!mean(is.na(target_column)) >= 0.5)`. Do you want to drop all columns or a single column based on grouping? The latter might be less obvious.

Answer (score 5):

**A dplyr solution**

For `select`ing columns based on a logical condition, we can use the selection helper `where()`, as in:

```
library(dplyr)

threshold <- 0.5 #for a 50% cut-off

df %>% select(where(~mean(is.na(.)) < threshold))
```

For `filter`ing rows, `dplyr`s `if_any()` and `if_all()` will handle cases of 100 or 0% cutoffs, as in `df %>% filter(if_any(everything(), ~is.na(.x)))`.
For solutions with other threshold values, you can use `rowMeans`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(rowMeans(is.na(.)) < threshold)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another tips ro filter df which has 50 NaNs in columns:

```
## Remove columns with more than 50% NA
rawdf.prep1 <- rawdf[, sapply(rawdf, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))/nrow(rawdf)*100 <= 50]
```

This will result a df with only NaN in columns not greater to 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we need to keep the sample data `NHANES` and columns with missing values less than or equal to 3%:

```
library(NHANES)
library(naniar)
library(dplyr)

select_cols <- naniar::miss_var_summary(NHANES) %>% 
  filter(pct_miss <= 3) %>% 
  pull(variable)
names.use <- names(NHANES)[(names(NHANES) %in% select_cols)]
NHANES %>% 
  select(c(names.use))
# NHANES[, c(names.use)]
```

Out:

[image]