# Select columns in dataset where at least 90 percent of the values are bigger than zero

Tags: r, select

I want to select the columns in a dataset where at least 90 percent of the values are bigger than zero. Would appreciate it if someone could show me a code that does this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove % of Items in Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68592376/remove-of-items-in-columns)

Comment: Although the question is slightly different, your answer is pretty much alreade answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68592376/remove-of-items-in-columns/68592582#68592582

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with R base:

Reproducible data example:

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100, 1.5), 10))
```

Solution:

```r
df[colMeans(df > 0) > 0.9]
```

Comment: Why not use `colMeans` instead?
`df[colMeans(df>0)>0.9]`

Comment: You’re right! I just didn’t think about it

Answer (score 0):

We can use `select(where)`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% select(where(~mean(.x>0)>0.9))
```