# Fill missing values by group using linear regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, na, missing-data

I have a dataset with about 50 columns (all indicators I got from World Bank), Country Code and Year. These 50 columns are not all complete, and I would like to fill in the missing values based on an lm fit for the column for that specific country. For example:

[image]

Doing this for a single country and a single column is absolutely fine when following these steps here: [Filling NA using linear regression in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634504/filling-na-using-linear-regression-in-r)

However, I have over 180 different countries I want to do this to. And I want this to work for each indicator per country (so 50 columns total) So in a way, each country and each column would have its own linear regression model that fills out the missing values.

Here is how it looked after I did the steps above: This is the expected output for ONE column. I would like to do this for EVERY column by individual country groups.

[image]

However, the data looks like this:

[image]

There are numerous countries and columns that I want to perform this on just like the post above.

This is for a project I am working on for my data-mining / statistics class. Any help would be appreciated and thanks so much in advance!

**EDIT**

I tried this:

```
# Reading CSV File
WorldBank=read.csv(file.choose(),header=T, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
colnames(WorldBank)[1] <- "Country_Code"
colnames(WorldBank)[2] <- "Year"



Countries <- t.data.frame(distinct((WorldBank)[1])) # to create an 
array of distinct countries I can loop over
CountryCount <- ncol(Countries) #this is what I intend to use
CountryCountDemo <- 1 # this is what I used for this example to only look at one country.
# Making new data
Worldbankone <- WorldBank

#CountryVarList <- names(Worldbankone[,3:57]) # Column 3 to 57. Not including year and country code.
df_total = data.frame() # Final data that will hold each iteration

for (i in 1:CountryCountDemo) {
  for (j in names(Worldbankone[,3:57])){

      country_temp <- Countries[i]
      Worldbanktemp <- Worldbankone %>% filter(Country_Code == 
      country_temp)
# If entire column has a null, make it all 0 (this needs to happen to perform linear regression on each column with all NAs)

if (all(is.na(c(Worldbanktemp[[j]]))) == TRUE) {
  
  Worldbanktemp[[j]] <- 0 
  
} else {
  
 


# Staging data to keep all values that do not have an NA value for that column for linear regression model
Worldbanktemp2 <- Worldbanktemp %>% filter(!is.na(.[[j]]))

# Creating fit. The only way to incorporate a variable like 'j' is by pasting it in.
fit <- lm(formula = paste0("`",j,"` ~ Year"), data = Worldbanktemp2)
# making a list that holds all the predicted values
pred = predict(fit,Worldbanktemp)



# Here is where things go wrong...
# I cannot used mutate here. It has no impact on the Worldbanktemp3 when I mutate Worldbanktemp. I tried both if_else and ifelse. I also tried as.name(j) and unquote(j) and !!as.name(j). 
Worldbanktemp3 <- Worldbanktemp %>% 
  # Replace NA with pred in var1
  mutate(!!j := if_else(is.na(!!as.name(j)), pred, !!as.name(j)))}
#df_total = rbind(df_total,Worldbanktemp3)}
#Fitting code before this
#Worldbankresult <-rbind(Worldbankresult,Worldbanktemp2)


}}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
# Reproducible example
sampledata2 = structure(list(Country_Code = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("", "ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "ALB", "AND", 
                                                                            "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", "ASM", "ATG", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BDI", 
                                                                            "BEL", "BEN", "BFA", "BGD", "BGR", "BHR", "BHS", "BIH", "BLR", 
                                                                            "BLZ", "BMU", "BOL", "BRA", "BRB", "BRN", "BTN", "BWA", "CAF", 
                                                                            "CAN", "CHE", "CHI", "CHL", "CHN", "CIV", "CMR", "COD", "COG", 
                                                                            "COL", "COM", "CPV", "CRI", "CUB", "CUW", "CYM", "CYP", "CZE", 
                                                                            "DEU", "DJI", "DMA", "DNK", "DOM", "DZA", "ECU", "EGY", "ERI", 
                                                                            "ESP", "EST", "ETH", "FIN", "FJI", "FRA", "FRO", "FSM", "GAB", 
                                                                            "GBR", "GEO", "GHA", "GIB", "GIN", "GMB", "GNB", "GNQ", "GRC", 
                                                                            "GRD", "GRL", "GTM", "GUM", "GUY", "HKG", "HND", "HRV", "HTI", 
                                                                            "HUN", "IDN", "IMN", "IND", "IRL", "IRN", "IRQ", "ISL", "ISR", 
                                                                            "ITA", "JAM", "JOR", "JPN", "KAZ", "KEN", "KGZ", "KHM", "KIR", 
                                                                            "KNA", "KOR", "KWT", "LAO", "LBN", "LBR", "LBY", "LCA", "LIE", 
                                                                            "LKA", "LSO", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MAC", "MAF", "MAR", "MCO", 
                                                                            "MDA", "MDG", "MDV", "MEX", "MHL", "MKD", "MLI", "MLT", "MMR", 
                                                                            "MNE", "MNG", "MNP", "MOZ", "MRT", "MUS", "MWI", "MYS", "NAM", 
                                                                            "NCL", "NER", "NGA", "NIC", "NLD", "NOR", "NPL", "NRU", "NZL", 
                                                                            "OMN", "PAK", "PAN", "PER", "PHL", "PLW", "PNG", "POL", "PRI", 
                                                                            "PRK", "PRT", "PRY", "PSE", "PYF", "QAT", "ROU", "RUS", "RWA", 
                                                                            "SAU", "SDN", "SEN", "SGP", "SLB", "SLE", "SLV", "SMR", "SOM", 
                                                                            "SRB", "SSD", "STP", "SUR", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE", "SWZ", "SXM", 
                                                                            "SYC", "SYR", "TCA", "TCD", "TGO", "THA", "TJK", "TKM", "TLS", 
                                                                            "TON", "TTO", "TUN", "TUR", "TUV", "TZA", "UGA", "UKR", "URY", 
                                                                            "USA", "UZB", "VCT", "VEN", "VGB", "VIR", "VNM", "VUT", "WSM", 
                                                                            "XKX", "YEM", "ZAF", "ZMB", "ZWE"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2000L, 
                                                                                                                                            2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
                                                                                                                                            2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
                                                                                                                                            2019L, 2020L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
                                                                                                                                            2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 
                                                                                                                                            2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L), EG.ELC.ACCS.ZS = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            NA, 22.29526901, 28.09996223, 33.9016037, 42.4, 45.52068329, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            42.7, 43.22201891, 69.1, 68.98294067, 89.5, 71.5, 97.7, 97.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            98.71562195, 97.7, NA, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            100, 100, 100, 100, 99.9, 100, 99.95, 99.98, 99.89, 99.89, 100, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            100), NY.GDP.COAL.RT.ZS = c(NA, NA, 0.004340991, 0.007421791, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.016454885, 0.010903631, 0.011152411, 0.076415204, 0.224465173, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.126422321, 0.212188085, 0.495356516, 0.270285101, 0.237255122, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.226599986, 0.162117663, 0.24730234, 0.397626964, 0.535542773, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.373839671, NA, 0.000620564, 0.001277136, 0.000274595, 0.000890331, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.006822021, 0.003077833, 0.002931413, 0.004030065, 0.013985094, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.000729611, 0.001394767, 0.000801741, 0.000360916, 0.000108033, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0, 0.005924115, 0.00038768, 0.015576529, 0.033583408, 0.024377128
                                                                                                                                                                                            ), NY.GDP.FRST.RT.ZS = c(NA, NA, 0.958003595, 0.664331186, 0.387787089, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.332204753, 0.454077242, 0.342748815, 0.353698168, 0.274778262, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.358436235, 0.309317612, 0.263852446, 0.259193525, 0.267631558, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.290360037, 0.397862173, 0.26727029, 0.335310319, 0.367809087, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     NA, 0.126636828, 0.062644576, 0.066551134, 0.062998763, 0.053996825, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.04788751, 0.054154854, 0.074771754, 0.069714105, 0.074808569, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.065976686, 0.210223146, 0.182521796, 0.165152821, 0.169255817, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.191365261, 0.15742073, 0.176432723, 0.169991392, 0.16648548
                                                                                                                                                                                            )), row.names = c(NA, 41L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already know how to do this for one dataframe with a single country, you are very close to your solution. But to make this easy on yourself, you need to do a few things.

1. Create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) using dput. The `janitor` library has the clean_names() function to fix columns names.
2. Write your own interpolation function that takes a dataframe with one country as the input, and returns an interpolated dataframe for one country.
3. [Pivot_longer](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) to get all the data columns into a one parameterized column.
4. Use the `dplyr` function [group_split](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_split.html) to take your large multicountry dataframe, and break it into a list of dataframes, one for each country and parameter.
5. Use the `purrr` function [map](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) to map each of the dataframes in the list to a new list of interpolate dataframes.
6. Use dplyr's [bind_rows](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html) to convert the list interpolated dataframes back into one dataframe, and [pivot_wider](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) to get your original data shape back.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(janitor)

my_country_interpolater<-function(single_country_df){
  
  data_to_build_model<-single_country_df %>%
    filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
    select(year,value)
  
  years_to_interpolate<-single_country_df %>%
    filter(is.na(value)) %>%
    select(year)
  
  fit<-lm(value ~ year, data = data_to_build_model)
  value = predict(fit,years_to_interpolate)
  
  
  interpolated_data<-tibble(years_to_interpolate, value)
  
  single_country_interpolated_df<-bind_rows(data_to_build_model,interpolated_data) %>% 
    mutate(country_code=single_country_df$country_code[1]) %>%
    mutate(parameter=single_country_df$parameter[1]) %>%  # added this for the additional parameters
    select(country_code, year, parameter, value) %>%
    arrange(year) 
  
  return (single_country_interpolated_df)
}

interpolated_df <-sampledata2 %>%
  clean_names() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(3:5),names_to = "parameter", values_to="value") %>%
  group_by(country_code,parameter) %>%
  group_split() %>% 
 # map(preprocess_data) %>% if you need a preprocessing step
  map(my_country_interpolater) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = parameter, values_from=value, names_glue = "{parameter}_interp")
```

Comment: Hi, I added an edit to my post can you please take a look? I am having trouble with the mutate() function. It does not mutate the table I connected the pipe to.

Comment: Hi Danny, see edits above where I've written the interpolater function. The first step to getting help is generating a reproducible problem using dput. I found a data set similar to your, and just used the first few countries. Trying to do this your way with loop can get really confusing, as there are a lot of things to keep track of. That's why i like map. It keeps the code clean and functional.

Comment: Hi @joe-erinjeri, Thank you so much for your help it looks very elegant. But I wanted to ask how do I apply this function on multiple columns? My problem has been dynamically doing this for each column I have. This is great for single-column examples but I have about 55 I need to do this on. Is there a way to dynamically reference column names instead of 'EG_ELC'?

Comment: Hi @Danny, Yes. S

Comment: Hi @Danny, Yes, but here is the best part. You don't need to dynamically reference the columns. First, pivot_longer your dataset, so that you have a new column called parameters (which reference each column), and a column with values that have each value. Now when you when you do the group_by, group_by both country code and parameter. Amazingly, with minimal modifications, your interpolater function still works. At the end of the pipeline, pivot_wider to get your original data back.

Comment: Hi @joe-erinjeri, I tested this and it worked! This is an amazing solution. I only fell into a problem because some columns are completely null for some countries, while not null for others. I tried to do these steps here to clear the columns if they were all NAs for each group https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848156/delete-columns-rows-with-more-than-x-missing. I specifically added purrr::discard(~sum(is.na(.x))/length(.x)* 100 => 99) in the pipeline after group_split() and it did not work. Is there a way to fill these empty columns when 0 when the whole column is empty for that group?

Comment: Just to clarify this is because when an empty column for each group is inputted into lm(), it throws an error

Comment: Try to consider your overall pipeline. if some of the list of dataframes need pre-processing, make a new function called preprocess_data and put in in the pipeline before country interpolator. I have made and edit so you can see where it goes, .